# New to intellij android studio, can't open sample projects without Gradle error

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

i just switched to intellij and pretty new to android development.. I've been working on one app for 5 moth and now that i moved it to intellij android studio my options menus became invisible. I've been reading a lot and trying to catch up with newest features that are available now today.

By biggest pain is that im hitting this error ->

Failed to refresh Gradle project 'ActionBarCompat-ListPopupMenu' You are using Gradle version 1.8, which is not supported. Please use version 1.9. Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (

I did search on this problem and some pages suggesting changing classpath to soething like 
build:gradle:0.7.+ but that doest help..

What am i doing wrong? All i need is just to make those examples from android to work..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Gradle wrapper file is at the path  ***(project-root)*/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**. The `distributionUrl` property is where you set the Gradle version; it's embedded in the URL:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip
```

Comment: i'm getting different error after changing this distributionUrl   ->>     Failed to refresh Gradle project 'ActionBarCompat-Basic' Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ResolvedComponentResult'.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you've updated to the newest *Android SDK Build-tools* version, the most current one is 19.0.3; if you haven't, then open the Android SDK manager and update.

Then look in the *build.gradle* file inside your project folder (not the one in the root folder). This first couple of lines should resemble something like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}
```

Set the class path to *com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+*.

Then further along in the same file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"
    ...
}
```

Set *buildToolsVersion* to *19.0.3* (the newest version).

Make sure Android Studio syncs the Gradle file changes. If it doesn't, restart Android Studio and/or rebuild the project. Then you should be good to go.

Comment: This version of the Android Gradle plugin will only work on Android Studio 0.5.0 or later.

Comment: Jaap, i did install all the 19.* abailiable buldTools, and this didnt help. Scott, are you saying that if  im running 0.4.2, i might see less issues if i update to 0.5.0?

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured this out.. Big thanks to Scott and Jaap.

I did updateof my intellij to 0.5.2, also i installed 19.0.3 ( newest build tools).
On few of the existing projects i had to change distributionUrl to 
 distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip

After rebuilding the project it worked like a charm.

Comment: Note that IF you use the wrapper then you need to invoke "gradlew" and not gradle if you run from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note to say : Scorr Berba's reply was probably the correct one. Also I'm not sure 1.11 can be used  - I used the wrapper (there is a lot of confusion here : the wrapper is the gradlew ["gradle*w*"rapper] to set the gradle used for my samples to 1.10 and you must set up your project to use the wrapper OR you can build from the command line e.g "./gradlew build".